# DB2 ODBC via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, db2, odbc

I am trying to create the ODBC System DSN 32 bit for DB2 ODBC Driver. Executed as Administrator.

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "PROKEY1" -DriverName "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1" -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=DB-Server", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=DB")
```

```
Add-OdbcDsn : Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed
(Installer error code: 11).
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-OdbcDsn -Name "PROKEY1" -DriverName "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1" -DsnTyp
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PROKEY1 (32-bit ODBC System DSN):Root/Microsoft/...SFT_OdbcDsnTask) [Add-OdbcDsn], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 0,Add-OdbcDsn
```

I am able to create the DSN via the GUI.

`Get-OdbcDsn`

`Name       : PROKEY
DsnType    : System
Platform   : 32-bit
DriverName : IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1
Attribute  : {}`

Comment: Your example shows `-Name "PROKEY"`, but the error mentions `-Name "PROKEY1"`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Can you configure it once with the GUI and then, when you've confirmed that it works, use `Get-OdbcDsn` to get the properties that you need to get the PowerShell command working?

Comment: @theo : that is a typo.

Comment: @BaconBits : Updating question with `Get-OdbcDsn` . I cant find any relevant info missing in my add DSN.

Answer (score 0):

To get your string to work on my server having IBM Data Server Client installed and the test instance of Db2 configured using `db2 catalog` I had to add `"DbAlias=TestDb2` where the alias matches

```
db2 catalog tcpip node TEST remote 00.1.222.33 server 5010
db2 catalog dcs database TestDb2 as xxxxxxxt
db2 catalog database TestDb2as TestDb2at node TEST
db2 terminate
```

So, this did work on my server.

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "PROKEY1" -DriverName "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1" -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=DB-Server", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=DB","DbAlias=TestDb2")
```

Had a similar error myself, found it explained here [Add-OdbcDsn giving error code 11](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/7ff44aad-8e90-4640-9f06-f13ec55429af/addodbcdsn-giving-error-code-11?forum=ITCG)

> There were parameters that the driver was requiring, that I was missing in my dsn.

But, if you then run the command you will get the same issue which lead me to search Stackoverflow - why is only the DbAlias set as parameter, and not the other ones? So question answered, but a new one has emerged.